# append element with jquery script

Tags: php, html, jquery, json

basically I have PHP and jquery code in my `<td>` that will allow inline editing

```
<td>
    <div contenteditable="true" onBlur="updateValue(this, 'lName', '<?php echo $id;?>')" onClick="activate(this)"><?php echo $lName; ?></div>
</td>
```

and I want to re-apply that same effect on another, ajax and JSON-based table whenever they get appended.

```
success: function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(dt) {
        $("#tbody2").append(
            "<tr>"+ 
            " <td><div contenteditable="true" onBlur="updateValue(this, 'lName', +dt.personId+ ") onClick="activate(this)">" +dt.lName+ "</div></td>"   +
            "</tr>"); 
    });
```

`dt.personId` and `dt.lName` do exist.

It keeps saying

> uncaught syntax error, missing ) after argument list

I would assume it would be an escaping problem for the function parameters but I can't recognize where.

Comment: I guess it's because you keep using `"` this `" <td><div contenteditable="true"` should maybe be `" <td><div contenteditable='true'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this `" <td><div contenteditable="true" onBlur="updateValue(this, 'lName', +dt.personId+ ")` If  you look at the line, jquery will think that you line starts and end at `" <td><div contenteditable="` because this is the first and next `"`

So you have to either swap some of the `"` with `'` or escape them by `\n`

```
$("#tbody2").append(
"<tr>"+ 
    " <td><div contenteditable='true' onBlur='updateValue(this, \'lName\'," +dt.personId+ ")' onClick='activate(this)'>" +dt.lName+ "</div></td>"   +
"</tr>"); });
```

Comment: Now I get an ```Uncaught Syntax error: unexpected end of input``` on blur. It works fine on the non-JSON lines though

Comment: This solution fixes the `"` inside `"` but then puts `'` inside a `'`  (`onblur='...this, 'lName',...`)  - so you get the next error.  Probably easiest to use backtick ` as the outer quote then make sure you don't nest `"` or `'` - alternatively, split your string and use the other as required. eg:  `"example ' " + 'and "'`

Comment: Or, ideally and easiest, don't use inline event handlers, add what you need as `data-` attributes and use a js/jquery event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You've mismatched of using brackets.

```
 data.forEach(function(dt){
    $("#tbody2").append(
       "<tr><td><div contenteditable='true' onBlur='updateValue(this, "+dt.lName+", +dt.personId )'  onClick='activate(this)"+dt.lName+"</div></td></tr>"
    );
  });
```